# Проблема при проверке input на пустое значение

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть элемент `input` с классом `.test` и на нем событие `input`:

```
var a;
$('.test').on('input', function() {
  a = this.value;
})
```

Вопрос вот в чем, я строю логику, в которой проверяю, пуст ли `input` и т.п.

Проблема в том, что если выделить `CTRL + A` и нажать `backspace` (стереть), а затем проверить поле на условие:

```
if (a == '' || a <= 0) {}
```

то это покажет `false`, хотя должно показать `true`.

Как корректно обработать этот недуг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого достаточно воспользоваться методом [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), который удалит пробелы вначале и конце строки, а потом "спросить" пустая ли у нас строка:

```js
$(".test").on("input", function() {
  const value = this.value.trim()
  if (value) {
    console.log("not empty")
  } else {
    console.log("empty")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" />
```